# VirtualizingStackPanel not aligning menu items vertical on applying theme

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, menuitem, virtualizingstackpanel

Before applying WPF theme - BureauBlue.xaml theme, I can see menu items aligning vertically with the below code:

```
<Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Menu.ItemsPanel>
```

But the same logic is aligning the menu items horizontally once I apply the theme.

Could you please assist me in resolving this?

Comment: Why would you use a VirtualizingStackPanel in a Menu?

Comment: Where are you applying this ItemsPanel, directly to the control itself?

Comment: I have solved this. Just to answer, VirtualizingStackPanel is used to align the menu items vertically. I am applying this control directly to the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the problem.

I am supposed to use VirtualizingStackPanel to display the menu items vertically.

In the theme style for Menu, StackPanel orientation is coded as Horizontal.

I just copied the code from the theme xaml and created a new style where the only change is Orientation from Horizontal to Vertical.

For the Menu, I have applied the new style as a DynamicResource.

It worked.

Thanks...